# Javascript - Need to Work With Elements With Generic Classes

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have some javascript written to accommodate my needs for some conditional formatting on a SharePoint page. There are a few tables, in web parts, in which I am making the changes to the style of some of the cells. I used a nodelist to accomplish my needs (no unique ids), and everything was working alright, until changes were made to the table which threw my nodelist references off (I knew it was inevitable..). I am wondering if anyone has input on how to better select or distinguish between elements that have the same class name and contain data that will change.

example:

```
<td class="asd"> blah blah blah </td>
<td class="asd"> content content </td>
<td class="asd"> test test test </td>
```

Comment: I will see if I am able to set a unique id. I am new to SharePoint, so I am not sure how locked down their markup is. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, removed my comment, since I guess a getElementyByClassName could work just as fine. :)

Comment: I was approaching in a similar way, using document.querySelectorAll("asd") to get all of the elements into a nodelist, and what I have works, but when another element with the same class is added to the page, the references I am using change, which I expected. I am wondering if there are any out of the ordinary suggestions about how I can access elements in a different way, so that when additional elements with the same class name are added to the page my previous references/variables using the nodelist locations are not lost.

Answer (score 0):

Select them using [**getElementsByClassName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('asd');
console.log(tds);
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].style.color = 'green';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="asd">blah blah blah</td>
    <td class="asd">content content</td>
    <td class="asd">test test test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was approaching in a similar way, using document.querySelectorAll("asd") to get all of the elements into a nodelist, and what I have works, but when another element with the same class is added to the page, the references I am using change, which I expected. I am wondering if there are any out of the ordinary suggestions about how I can access elements in a different way, so that when additional elements with the same class name are added to the page my previous references/variables using the nodelist locations are not lost.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

`var td=document.getElementsByClassName("asd");//returns array of elements by this class name
td[0]
td[1]
...`

Comment: I was approaching in a similar way, using document.querySelectorAll("asd") to get all of the elements into a nodelist, and what I have works, but when another element with the same class is added to the page, the references I am using change, which I expected. I am wondering if there are any out of the ordinary suggestions about how I can access elements in a different way, so that when additional elements with the same class name are added to the page my previous references/variables using the nodelist locations are not lost.